# jQuery: Append child element before child element

Tags: jquery, append, parent-child, appendchild

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div id="content">

    <div class="foobar"></div>
</div>
```

I want to append child elements inside `div#content` before the `div.foobar` element. How can do that?

Comment: `.prepend()` is your friend.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.insertBefore

Comment: @procrastinator The documentation can be intimidating and that's what this site is for. Anyway I was Googling it myself, this was the first result, and I got my answer (or at least was pointed in the right direction), so mission accomplished.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before I answer your question let me make something more clearer and easier to u so that you understand what your trying to

**Append**  means you can insert elements as child elements at the end of the selector

example `append() and appendTo()`

**Prepend**  means you can insert elements as child elements at the beginning of the selector

example `prepend() and prependTo()`

Notice that selector will be considered as a `parent`

**Before** means you can add elements just before the selector

example `before() and insertBefore()`

**After** means you can add elements just after the selector

example `after() and insertAfter()`

before and after `does not` treat selector as a `parent` element

Now to answer your question

You can do it using `prepend or before`

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="foobar"></div>
</div>

$("your element").insertBefore("#content div.foobar") // or
$("#content div.foobar").before("element") // or
$("#content").prepend("element") // or
$("element").prependTo("#content")
```

Notice the selector positions in `prepend() and prependTo()`

Comment: I love how you explained the functions first. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can use [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)/[insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) like

```
$('#content .foobar').before(newcontent)
$(newcontent).insertBefore('#content .foobar')
```

or if you want to insert new content as the first child of `#content` then use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$('#content').prepend(newcontent)
```

Comment: I guess you have misplaced the selector and content ? it should be insertBefore

Comment: @niko I think the A is correct. the only difference is in the method usage. `$(second).before(first)` and `$(first).insertBefore(second)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes but the second statement should be insertBefore i guess?

Comment: @niko ahh yes, I see it now.

Comment: @BlackSheep true, but does a String variable.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes , that's true.